# WindowsXP+7 on C:/D: :moving the System Partition

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning

I had installed Windows 7 on a separate 20gig partition, and I'm absolutely loving it! Plus I can now dual-boot, with my original WinXP residing on the C: drive. But I'm running out of disk space on D:, and I was able to shrink C: and expand D:.

But now I would like to make D: not just a Boot Partition, but an Active System Partition, without losing my ability to boot into Windows 7 (since it was created on a separate D: partition, not the current Active System C: Partition).

Any advice?

Comment: Why do you need it to be an active system partition? Both OS's boot fine?

Comment: I'm so confused trying to figure out what this guy wants.

Comment: Some info: [Changing Active Partition Can Make Your System Unbootable](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/228004)

Comment: Only 20gb for Windows 7? I figured you'd run out soon :D

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of programs on the markit that can extend a partition, using the free space from a different partition on the same HDD. One that we use in our office is Easeus partition master.

mtern